# Does it matter where you call useContext in React?

Tags: reactjs, use-context

For example, if I got an array *(the example has 4 elements, the real one 50)*:

```js
export default ["foo", "bar", "faz", "moo"];
```

Let's say I got the component that displays the data:

```js
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import PreferenceContext from '../contexts/PreferenceContext';

export default props => {
  const { accentColor } = useContext(PreferenceContext);

  return (
    <div style={{ color: accentColor }}>
      {props.foo}
    </div>
  );
}
```

next, I reuse that component in the parent component

```js
// FooCollection.js
import React from 'react';
import FooDisplay from './FooDisplay';
import fooArray from '../data/fooArray';

export default () => {
  return fooArray.map(fooItem => <FooDisplay foo={fooItem} />
}
```

this causes the `FooDisplay` component to be rendered times the amount of items in the array (thus calling `useContext` that many times also). So, if I got a bigger array with more items, will this impact performance noticeably? Or will I be better off using the `useContext` in the wrapper *(parent)* component and passing the preference on with `props`?

*in reality the component is nested three times, this causes prop passing clutter so that's why I went with context, however I can imagine it making the application slower if it calls the context so many times*

Answer (score 0):

Do not pre-optimize.

React is really fast and can do millions of executing each second, so you will not notice a low down.

If you notice a delay, measure how slow it really is, try to optimize it and see if that actually increases the speed. If not revert it. But do not worry about until you notice a lag.

But until then, do not bother and focus on writing maintainable code.